# Match exact phrase within a string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, match

I'm trying to determine whether a substring is in a string.
The issue I'm running into is that I don't want my function to return True if the substring is found within another word in the string.

For example: if the substring is; "Purple cow"
and the string is; "Purple cows make the best pets."
This should return False. Since cow isn't plural in the substring.

And if the substring was; "Purple cow"
and the string was; "Your purple cow trampled my hedge!"
would return True

My code looks something like this:

```
def is_phrase_in(phrase, text):
    phrase = phrase.lower()
    text = text.lower()

    return phrase in text


text = "Purple cows make the best pets!"
phrase = "Purple cow"
print(is_phrase_in(phrase, text)
```

In my actual code I clean up unnecessary punctuation and spaces in 'text' before comparing it to phrase, but otherwise this is the same. 
I've tried using re.search, but I don't understand regular expressions very well yet and have only gotten the same functionality from them as in my example.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jaques! Didn't notice I left that self. in there.

Comment: And thank you, everyone, for your responses!

Answer (score 11):

Since your phrase can have multiple words, doing a simple split and intersect won't work. I'd go with regex for this one:

```
import re

def is_phrase_in(phrase, text):
    return re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(phrase), text, re.IGNORECASE) is not None

phrase = "Purple cow"

print(is_phrase_in(phrase, "Purple cows make the best pets!"))   # False
print(is_phrase_in(phrase, "Your purple cow trampled my hedge!"))  # True
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! Looks like I nearly figured it out for myself. I tried for a while to figure out how to get my variable 'phrase' into re.search and never thought to use string formatting. Time to go educate myself on regular expressions!

Comment: @zwer - Why do you include `\b` in the regex pattern?

Comment: @Jubbles - to ensure there is a word boundary around the phrase being searched, otherwise it would capture partial phrase matches as well (i.e. _purple cows_ instead of just _purple cow_).

Answer (score 2):

**Using PyParsing:**

```py
import pyparsing as pp

def is_phrase_in(phrase, text):
    phrase = phrase.lower()
    text = text.lower()

    rule = pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Keyword(phrase))
    for t, s, e in rule.scanString(text):
      if t:
        return True
    return False

text = "Your purple cow trampled my hedge!"
phrase = "Purple cow"
print(is_phrase_in(phrase, text))
```

Which yields:

```py
True
```

Answer (score 0):

One can do this very literally with a loop

```
phrase = phrase.lower()
text = text.lower()

answer = False 
j = 0
for i in range(len(text)):
    if j == len(phrase):
        return text[i] == " "
    if phrase[j] == text[i]:
        answer = True
        j+=1
    else:
        j = 0 
        answer = False 
return answer
```

Or by splitting

```
phrase_words = phrase.lower().split()
text_words = text.lower().split()

return phrase_words in text_words
```

or using regular expressions

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("[^\w]" + text + ""[^\w]")
pattern.match(phrase.lower())
```

to say that we want no characters preceding or following our text, but whitespace is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions should do the trick

```
import re

def is_phrase_in(phrase, text):
    phrase = phrase.lower()
    text = text.lower()
    if re.findall('\\b'+phrase+'\\b', text):
        found = True
    else:
        found = False
    return found
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, hope this helps

```
 # Declares
 string = "My name is Ramesh and I am cool. You are Ram ?"
 sub = "Ram"

 # Check String For SUb String
 result = sub in string

 # Condition Check
 if result:

    # find starting position
    start_position = string.index(sub)

    # get stringlength
    length = len(sub)

    # return string
    output = string[start_position:len]
```

Comment: @Manpreet Singh